# Create a bat file with variables from another bat file

Tags: batch-file, escaping

I want to create a bat file with set variables from another bat file.
This is for a startup `.bat` file that maps network drives and copies some files to the local computer and looks at the system services that needs to run.

It also needs to create a log file every time the logon .bat file runs.  Here is a sample what I have done.

```
ECHO set SERVER IP=>>"V:\GENESIS\GENESIS INSTALL FILES\GenesisLogonUser.bat"
ECHO set DRIVE1=V>>"V:\GENESIS\GENESIS INSTALL FILES\GenesisLogonUser.bat"
ECHO set MAPDRIVE1=\\%SERVER IP%\v /P:Yes>>"V:\GENESIS\GENESIS INSTALL FILES\GenesisLogonUser.bat"
ECHO net use %DRIVE1%: %MAPDRIVE1% >>"%userprofile%\Documents\scripts\logonlog.txt">>"V:\GENESIS\GENESIS INSTALL FILES\GenesisLogonUser.bat"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape percent expansion of the variables. This can be done by doubling each `%` sign in a batch script:

```
set "VAR=Value"
echo %%VAR%%
```

This will echo:

> ```
> %VAR%
> ```

Note that this does not work directly in the console window; you need to do it like this instead:

```
>set "VAR=Value"

>echo ^%VAR^%
%VAR%
```

---

So to apply this to your script, it looks like this (I excluded `%USERPROFILE%` from the escaping as I do not know how you like it; of course you could write `%%USERPROFILE%%` instead as well):

```
(
    ECHO set "SERVER IP="
    ECHO set "DRIVE1=V"
    ECHO set "MAPDRIVE1=\\%%SERVER IP%%\v /P:Yes"
    ECHO net use %%DRIVE1%%: %%MAPDRIVE1%%^>^>"%USERPROFILE%\Documents\scripts\logonlog.txt"
) > "V:\GENESIS\GENESIS INSTALL FILES\GenesisLogonUser.bat"
```

Since there is some redirection in the echoed text, this needs to be escaped like `^>^>`.

I also put all `ECHO` commands within parentheses, which requires a single redirection operation only; this improves legibility and performance.

In addition, I improved the `set` syntax so that the entire assignment expression is placed in between a pair of quotation marks, which make it robust against special characters (the quotes do not become part of the value).